# What does the "upgrade" from a credit limit to a "credit access line" really mean?

Tags: credit-card

I've just received a letter from Chase saying that my card has been upgraded to no longer have a credit limit, but a "credit access line" (which they can continue to "refer to credit access line [sic] as credit line or credit limit").

Several articles online mention this as a sneaky trap, but what exactly is the problem for someone who checks their spending regularly? Are charges over some limit incurring a higher interest? The only "danger" I've seen is that the card member might be spending more than if they had hit the limit, but I never hit the limit anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify how your question is not answered by [this one](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/57510/my-credit-limit-is-now-a-credit-access-line-does-it-matter)?

Comment: @BrenBarn: I did search, as you might imagine, but SE didn't show the dupe question in this instance. I've just voted to close my own question as a duplicate.